# Step by step smartcontract debugging with truffle or brownie

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, brownie

I am writing smart-contracts with Vyper/Brownie or Solidity/Truffle.

In order to debug and test my smartcontracts, i want to execute them step by step.

Is there a way to do that exactly like we debug a c++ program with breakpoints for example.

Is there a way to see EVM instructions during this step by step debugging ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use the Debugger option in Remix to do exactly what you're after -> https://remix.ethereum.org/, fifth icon in the menu. Pretty sure you can't do either of these in Brownie or Truffle as you would with `gdb`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks i know this tool in remix but i want exactly the same thing with command line. I don't know how to do that with gdb because the entry point is the transaction hash...

Comment: Someone else might know of a tool, so I'll defer to whoever gives you a good answer :-) (`gdb` itself won't work because it doesn't understand EVM bytecode.)